# Why does adding another label to a query slow it down massively?

Tags: neo4j

Sorry about the vague wording, here's the issue. I've got a query that is running fast (4 secs) thanks to some help I got yesterday:

```
// polypeptide domain, protein HMM match and polypeptide (fast)
MATCH (pd:PolypeptideDomain) WITH pd LIMIT 5
MATCH (phm:ProteinHmmMatch)
WHERE (phm)-[:PART_OF]->(pd)
MATCH (p:Polypeptide)
WHERE (phm)-[:PART_OF]->(p)
RETURN phm,pd,p
```

This runs fast because I pick out 5 polypeptide domains, and after that, the related protein HMM match and polypeptides are quickly found.

So, I simply want to add the mRNA associated with the polypeptide -- it's a one-to-one relationship, every mRNA links one and only one polypeptide, so I'd think that additional match would be fast. Here's what I wrote:

```
// polypeptide domain, protein hmm match, polypeptide and mRNA (blows up)
MATCH (pd:PolypeptideDomain) WITH pd LIMIT 5
MATCH (phm:ProteinHmmMatch)
WHERE (phm)-[:PART_OF]->(pd)
MATCH (p:Polypeptide)
WHERE (phm)-[:PART_OF]->(p)
MATCH (m:mRNA)
WHERE (p)-[:TRANSLATION_OF]->(m)
RETURN phm,pd,p,m
```

This query never returns. I'm totally mystified, once again. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make this simple addition to the query work.

Comment: I'll add that the EXPLAIN diagram shows Polypeptide X mRNA being run as a gigantic Cartesian product at the top, which is mechanically why this is slow, but the question is really how I prevent that when I know that I've only got the five polypeptides resulting from the earlier part of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's growing out of control because for each `MATCH` result it's trying to find every combination of of every other `MATCH` result.

Also, you shouldn't use pattern matching in `WHERE` clauses generally unless you're getting into more complicated logic (like `NOT(<match syntax)`).  How about this?

```
MATCH (pd:PolypeptideDomain) WITH pd LIMIT 5
MATCH (phm:ProteinHmmMatch)-[:PART_OF]->(pd)
WITH pd, phm
MATCH (phm)-[:PART_OF]->(p:Polypeptide)
WITH pd, phm, p
MATCH (p)-[:TRANSLATION_OF]->(m:mRNA)
RETURN phm,pd,p,m
```

If any of those involve more than one relationship you can do a `collect` in the `WITH` like `WITH pd, collect(phm)`.

Looking at your matches, though, it seems like you might be able to get away with this:

```
MATCH (pd:PolypeptideDomain) WITH pd LIMIT 5
MATCH (pd)<-[:PART_OF]-(phm:ProteinHmmMatch)-[:PART_OF]->(p:Polypeptide)-[:TRANSLATION_OF]->(m:mRNA)
RETURN phm,pd,p,m
```

Again, if there are many relationships between the two then your data will be sort of de-normalized.